# Differentiate this power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am working on a problem which involves the differentiation of a power series.
I know that that the following holds.

---

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n.$
Let $f: (-R, R) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by this power series, with

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n. \space \space (*)$$

Then $f$ is differentiable at every point of $(-R, R)$ and

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n a_n x^{n-1}.$$

---

Now, I am working on a problem in which I must show that the function $J(x),$ defined by the power series

$$J(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n!)^2}(x/2)^{2n},$$

satisfies the differential equation

$$xJ''(x) + J'(x) + xJ(x) = 0.$$

I am having an issue with finding the first derivative of $J(x).$
This is because $J(x)$ has not been written in the way that I am used to (see $(*)$ above).
I have looked at the first part of the model solution, which states that

$$J'(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 2n}{2(n!)^2}(x/2)^{2n - 1}.$$

Could someone please help me understand why this is so, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $$(Mess)(x/2)^{2n}=\frac{Mess}{2^{2n}}x^{2n}=a_{2n}x^{2n}$$
Differentiate $x^{2n}$ to get $2nx^{2n-1}$
$2n$ goes into the numerator of the mess.
$2n-1$ of the twos in the denominator come out, combine with $x^{2n-1}$ to give $(x/2)^{2n-1}$.  Only one two is left in the denominator.